# How to access axios inside vuex store actions?

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3, quasar-framework, laravel-sanctum

In my vuex actions, I can access Axios using this._vm.$axios before, but when I update quasar to v2 and use composition API vue3 now, $axios got undefined.

The Axios plugin is defined in boot files

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import axios from 'axios'
const instance = axios.create({
  headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  withCredentials: true
})

export default boot (({ app }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$axios = instance
})
```

Inside my vuex actions.js I cannot access the Axios which is now I guess is globally available

```
export function login ({ commit, dispatch }, credentials) {
return this._vm.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', credentials)
.then(res => {
  return this._vm.$axios.post('/login', credentials)
})
.then((res) => {
  commit('setLoggedIn', true)
  commit('setUser', res.data)
  return Promise.resolve(res.data)
})
}
```

Comment: quasar v2 docs mentioned the of usage axios in vuex store, https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

Axios is configured in a boot file. You can import it from there using

```js
// any vue(x store) file
import { api } from "boot/axios";
```